# How do I remove the "delete" option for admins using activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to understand why I am not able to remove the "delete" option for admins using active admin.

In the past, I've tried deleting the admin button but once the server is ran, no changes are being made.

I have added the following line, this gets rid of 1 delete button. However, there are 2 which need to be deleted.

Example of delete button being used: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/active_admin_sidebar/0.0.4

```
  config.remove_action_item(:destroy)
```

After researching and finding this code, this also did not work.

```
link_to I18n.t('active_admin.delete'), admin_resource_path(resource), method: :delete, data: { confirm: I18n.t('active_admin.delete_confirmation') }, class: "delete_link" if resource.deletable?
```

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  config.remove_action_item(:destroy)

  permit_params :email, :password, :password_confirmation


  index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :email
    column :current_sign_in_at
    column :sign_in_count
    column :created_at
    actions
  end

  filter :email
  filter :current_sign_in_at
  filter :sign_in_count
  filter :created_at

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :email
      f.input :password
      f.input :password_confirmation
    end
    f.actions
  end

end
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip "destroy" action in buttons, you have two ways:

1. Pass list of allowed actions:

```rb
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  # ... other columns
  actions :index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit
end
```

2. Use `except` key for `actions` method to pass disallowed actions:

```
index do
  selectable_column
  id_column
  # ... other columns
  actions :all, except: :destroy
end
```

Or you can disable `:destroy` action for each page for resource:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  actions :all, :except => :destroy
end
```

Or you can clear all actions for resource:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  config.clear_action_items!

  # After this you can go ahead and define custom 
  # action items as you please
end
```

Sources:

1. https://activeadmin.info/2-resource-customization.html
2. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/341
3. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/760

Comment: `actions :all, except: :destroy`, `actions :index, :show, :new, :create, :update, :edit` syntax WITHIN `index` block is not supported. I'm surprised that (1) the author posted it without trying, (2) topic starter accepted it without trying